# How is current zoom level determined for mobile browser in leaflet?

Tags: mobile, leaflet

I have a web map that is used primarily in a regular computer browser. (non-mobile devices)
I am trying to port it over to be usable in mobile versions of browsers. When you click the zoom control +/- the map zooms in/out by one level. The mouse scroll wheel mimics this event.
In my experience a more common way to zoom in and out on a mobile map is to use the pinch zoom. When a user zooms in/out by using their two fingers (spreading apart or moving together) **how is the zoom level determined after this event?** 
I would like to know this because I have tile layers turned on in the map that are working when I use the zoom control, but when I use the more common method it freezes. The map is otherwise completely stable in the regular browser.
using 0.7.2 leaflet, testing on iPad using current chrome browser
**edit** I should note that the map container css is not set up the way the [mobile tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples/mobile.html) is. I have a side navabr that take up about 1/3 of the screen.

Comment: looks like this is a [known issue](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/1922).  have you tried setting zoomAnimation to true?

Comment: _zoomAnimation: false helped with the general crashing_ I was experiencing but not with the layers altogether. I am thinking I will need to force a redraw or something, Thanks @sfletche